# Where does adb put uninstalled apps on the device?

Tags: android, adb

I have `adb` running and device is connected to my System in debugging mode

I want to find uninstalled apps using command in `adb shell`.What command can i use?

Answer (score -1):

just type on your terminal or command prompt

```
adb uninstall <package name of application>
```

i hope it will work for you.

Comment: thanks Yogendra, but i want know what apps uninstalled.i don't know name of apps. do you what i mean??:(

Comment: those app which is installed on your device. and you want delete it using adb command-tool then you can use above command then it will delete application from your device.